# How to fix "Cause: invalid type code: 8F"

Tags: java, android

Cause: invalid type code: 8F this error raise when try to take apk build.

Already I tried.. -- clean and rebuild -- Invalidate and restart -- jdk path setting -- experimental option

Android studio version 3.3.1

gradle version -- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

**project level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app level gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'nl.psdcompany:duo-navigation-drawer:2.0.6'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}
```

I attached my app and project level gradle file.

Comment: Please post Android Studio version, and gradle version

Comment: @theapache64 .. please check it

Comment: Can you try disabling `Only sync the active variant` via `File -> Settings -> Experimental` ?

Comment: I also tried this.

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` files (both app and project) ?

Comment: @theapache64 ..check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193255/discussion-between-theapache64-and-gayathri).